# Can not validate email field using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, email

I have one issue in validation of email using Angular.js.In my code i am using `ng-message` to display the validation message.for some invalid type email(`e.g-@abc.com`),it showing the validation message but in some case if i am typing like this `.com@abc` its not showing any validation message.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Email Id :</span>
    <div ng-class="{ 'has-error': billdata.email.$touched && billdata.email.$invalid }">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="contactno" class="form-control" placeholder="User email" ng-model="user_email" >
 </div>
</div>
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.email.$error" ng-if="billdata.email.$touched">
<p ng-message="email" style="color:#F00;">This needs to be a valid email</p>
</div>
```

Here i need this field will validate with proper email format(`i.e-abc@gmail.com`).Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Use `ng-pattern` with email regex

Comment: or u use own code in js

Comment: i did it like this `ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/"`.